# Jsoup getElementsByAttributeValueMatching

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

[the JSoup discussion page suggested I ask my question here.]

So, I am no regex expert, but I'm wondering about the results I get from the jsoup
getElementsByAttributeValueMatching() method.

If I have an html page that has (among others) the following links:

```
<a href="/tweb/tiles/twr/EIDS_AT_20130108T134335/01/">Parent Directory</a>
<a href="1357681618315/">1357681618315/</a>
<a href="1357681649996/">1357681649996/</a>
```

And I query with:

```
Elements dirs = baseDir.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching("href", Pattern.compile("[0-9]+/"));
```

hoping to get just the 2 links that have only numbers (and a slash at the end.)

However, I get all 3 links back.

I wrote a quick test program to check java's Pattern Matcher response to that regex with the 3 href strings, and it returns only the two with only numbers as I would expect:

```
String a = "/tweb/tiles/twr/EIDS_AT_20130108T134335/01/";
String b = "1357681618315/";
String c = "1357681649996/";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+/");

System.out.println("a:"+ p.matcher(a).matches());
System.out.println("b:"+ p.matcher(b).matches());
System.out.println("c:"+ p.matcher(c).matches());
```

returns:
a:false
b:true
c:true

So, my question is, what am I missing?

thanks,
Linus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jsoup uses [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29), not [`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29). So, you need to supply `^` and `$` yourself.

```
Elements dirs = baseDir.getElementsByAttributeValueMatching(
    "href", Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+/$"));
```

Here are javadoc extracts of relevance explaining the difference *(emphasis mine)*:

> ### find
>
> ...
>
> #### Returns:
>
> `true` if, and only if, a *subsequence* of the input sequence matches this matcher's pattern

> ### matches
>
> ...
>
> #### Returns:
>
> `true` if, and only if, the *entire* region sequence matches this matcher's pattern

As to why Jsoup uses `find()` instead of `matches()`, that's a question you've to ask to its creator.

Comment: Indeed.  I guess perhaps the docs might mention that.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[attr*=valContaining]` and `[attr~=regex]`when we use select in jsoup.

Elements dirs = baseDir.select([attr~=regex]);

attr----> attribute
regex-----> regex applied on the value of that attribute

refer to the docs here https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html